# What's the purpose of allowing to open mobile web site on desktop?

Tags: discussion, support, mobile-web

I can see that mobile web site is allowed to open on desktop for all stack exchange sites.
So What's the purpose of allowing to open mobile web site on desktop?

[image: Sample screen shot of Meta]

Answer (score 8):

1. False positives might occur i.e. browser that appears to be desktop but is actually mobile. In such case, not letting the user view the mobile theme would be very bad.
2. Easier debug: when something isn't working properly in the mobile theme, it usually can be observed on desktop browser as well, running the mobile theme.

Comment: I'd also suggest that in a bandwidth-restricted environment, the mobile site can be handy because it will use less data.

Comment: @AlE. probably, but need to look into the actual requests to be certain.